# PHP function for returning array with unique indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple problem. Lets say I have an array

Array

```
0   
product_id  233
slug    "zotac-geforce-gtx-1070-amp-extreme-edition-8gb-zt-p10700b-10p"

1   
product_id  227
slug    "zotac-geforce-gtx-1060-mini-6gb-gddr5-zt-p10600a-10l"

2   
product_id  233
slug    "zotac-geforce-gtx-1070-amp-extreme-edition-8gb-zt-p10700b-10p"
```

Now if you see there are two products having same product_id! I don't want that I am trying to get this array filtered from duplicate products

This is what I tried but it doesn't work

```
$temp_products = array();
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        if(count($temp_products) > 0)
        {
            foreach($temp_products as $temp_product)
            {
                if($temp_product['product_id'] != $product['product_id'])
                {
                    $temp_products[] = $product;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $temp_products[] = $product;
        }
    }
```

It returns the same array as the original one. and `$products` is the main array having the data.

Comment: array_filter removes duplicates if data is the same

Comment: You could also check [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and its comments.

Comment: $products array came from elasticsearch result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this! But I would definitely suggest using `array_filter` or `array_unique` will post an example later. Try this.

```
$temp_products = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($products as $product)
    {

        if(count($temp_products) > 0)
        {
            //foreach($temp_products as $temp_product)
            //{
                if($temp_products[$count]['product_id'] != $product['product_id'])
                {
                    $temp_products[] = $product;
                }
            //}
        }
        else
        {
            $temp_products[] = $product;
        }

    }
```

Using `array_unqiue`

```
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
       $temp_products[] = $product;
    }

    dd(array_unique($temp_products));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use a helper array to keep track of already present ids.

```
$temp_products = array();
$already_present = array();
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
      $id = $product['product_id'];
      if ( isset($already_present[ $id ] ) ) continue;
      $temp_products[] = $product;
      $already_present[ $id ] = '';
    }

$products = $temp_products;
```